# How can I get an image taken from my camera and add it as a marker on google maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Okay so what I am trying to do is to long click on my map and then take a photo using the camera intent and then return that photo as a marker on the point of the map where the user "long Clicked"

What works is the long click and then taking the picture.
What does not work is returning that image to the map as a marker.

This is what I am using to add the marker and take the image using the camera:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng mylocation = new LatLng(-xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylocation).title("Marker in mylocation"));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mylocation).zoom(12).build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/My Folder";
            imageFolderPath = root + "/saved_images";
            File imagesFolder = new File(imageFolderPath);
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            imageName = "test.png";
            File image = new File(imageFolderPath, imageName);
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        }
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, LatLng latlng) {
            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                try {
                    GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                    bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latlng)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is the GetImageThumbnail Class:

```
public class GetImageThumbnail {

private static int getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(double ratio) {
    int k = Integer.highestOneBit((int) Math.floor(ratio));
    if (k == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return k;
}

public Bitmap getThumbnail(Uri uri, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener test)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream input = ((Context) test).getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    onlyBoundsOptions.inDither = true;// optional
    onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// optional
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
    input.close();
    if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -2)
            || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -2))
        return null;

    int originalSize = Math.max(onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight, onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth);

    double ratio = (originalSize > 200) ? (originalSize / 175) : 0.5;

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
    bitmapOptions.inDither = true;
    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// optional
    input = ((Context) test).getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
    input.close();
    return bitmap;
  }
}
```

As I mentioned the camera intent launches and I can take a picture, but after the picture has been taken it returns to the map but with no marker?  There are also no error messages or anything I can find as to why its not displaying the marker/image.

I am sure I am doing something wrong here but can't figure out what?

Thanks

Comment: The `onActivityResult` signature is not right - e.g. try using `@Override` and verify it produces an error.  Where did you find that signature?  Depending on what you want, you either can use the `LatLng` in the long press or the user's current position - both of which you can get. Recommend removing the `LatLng` parameter in `onActivityResult`, verify it is invoked, @Override doesn't produce error and use `LatLng` from one of the two sources mentioned.